# Add to a list by Class

Tags: python, class, python-2.7

I got an exercise 
Write a class called GameBoard which contains the property called Animal_list.

Write method called Add_animal which receives an object of type Animal and adds it to the list.

Write a method that accepts direction, and randomly chooses an animal from the list and Mozizh the animal randomly

Write a method that checks if the animal moves the point that is already in another animal, the animal that's there to eat it, they took the dead animal from the list Animal_list, and add it to a new list dead animal on behalf of dead animals

This is my code :

```
animal_list=[]
dead_animal=[]

class Point:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x=0
        self.y=0
    def __str__(self):
        return ("location (%d,%d)"% self.x,self.y)



class Animall:
    def __init__(self):
        self.spped=0
        self.location = Point()
        self.name =""
    def __self__(self):
        return "%s,%d,%d,%d"%    (self.name,self.spped,self.location.x,self.location.y)

    def __str__(self):
        return "name = %s ,spped : %d , location (%d,%d)"% (self.name,self.spped,self.location.x,self.location.y)


class GameBoard(Animall):
    def __init__(self):
    #animal_list=[]
    #dead_animal=[]
    pass


def add_animall(self,a):
    animal_list.append([[a.location.x,a.location.y],a.name])


def move_random(self,b):
    r =randint(0,len(animal_list))-1
    if b== "up":
        animal_list[r][0][1] += randint(0,10)
    if b == "down":
        animal_list[r][0][1] -= randint(0,10)
    if b=="left":
        animal_list[r][0][0] -= randint(0,10)
    elif b == "right":
        animal_list[r][0][0] += randint(0,10)
    x=0
    for i in animal_list:
        if animal_list[r][0][0] == i[0][0] and animal_list[r][0][1] == i[0][1]:
            dead_animal.append([animal_list[r][1],[animal_list[r][0][0],animal_list[r][0][1]]])
            animal_list.remove(animal_list[x])
        else:
            for i in animal_list:
                if i[1]==animal_list[r][1]:
                     i[0]=[animal_list[r][0][0],animal_list[r][0][1]]

        x+=1



a = Animall()
a.name="a"
c= Animall()
c.name="c"
d =Animall()
d.name="d"
e= Animall()
e.name="e"
b = GameBoard()
b.add_animall(a)
b.add_animall(c)
b.add_animall(d)
b.add_animall(e)

b.move_random("left")
print animal_list,dead_animal
b.move_random("right")
print animal_list,dead_animal
b.move_random("up")
print animal_list,dead_animal
b.move_random("down")
print animal_list,"\n",dead_animal
```

and this is the output

```
[[[0, 0], 'c'], [[0, 0], 'e']] [['a', [-8, 0]], ['c', [0, 0]]]
[[[0, 0], 'e']] [['a', [-8, 0]], ['c', [0, 0]], ['c', [4, 0]]]
[] [['a', [-8, 0]], ['c', [0, 0]], ['c', [4, 0]], ['e', [0, 1]]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my file address", line 87, in   <module>
    b.move_random("down")
  File "my file address", line 44, in  move_random
    animal_list[r][0][1] -= randint(0,10)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Why he placing e,d location in different order from A and C?

Comment: *"I got on that an error"* What error? Can you post a full traceback of the error?

Comment: What error are you getting and on what line?

Comment: "TypeError: unbound method add_animall() must be called with GameBoard instance as first argument (got Animall instance instead)"

Answer (score 0):

Your `GameBoard` class should be

```
class GameBoard():
    def __init__(self):
        animal_list = []
    def add_animall(self,a):
        animal_list.append([[a.location.x,a.location.y],a.name])
```

Then you would use it as follows

```
a = Animal1()
g = GameBoard()
g.add_animall(a)
```

The error is telling you that you can't call `GameBoard.add_animall`, it needs an actual instance of that class to call the method from.

Answer (score 0):

In GameBoard you need to set up an empty `animal_list`, you then need to access this with `self`
Also I dont think you need to inherit from `Animall` here, but may have misunderstood.

```
class GameBoard():
    def __init__(self):
        self.animal_list = []

   def add_animal(self,a):
        self.animal_list.append([[a.location.x,a.location.y],a.name])
```

When you use the class, you first create an instance, then call the method on that:

```
a = Animal()
gb = GameBoard()
gb.add_animal(a)
```

I also changed the spelling to animal thoughout as I thought it was a little confusing